# powershell script to remove all data after 1st comma in a line

Tags: powershell-3.0

I'm having a time getting powershell to just delete everything after the first comma in a small txt file,

my data comes in like this;

```
00,00,00
```

I just need the first 00, nothing else,

here is what I am trying , any ideas??

```
(Get-Content –path C:\Users\USER\Desktop\RESULT2.csv) -replace '\s*,\s*' | select -Skip 2 | Out-File –path C:\Users\USER\Desktop\RESULT2.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to really understand your question

If your file looks like this :

```
00,Coucou
01,Hello
02,Au Revoir
```

You can use this :

```
Import-Csv C:\temp\tes.csv -Header a,b | % {$_.a}
```